# How to import code from SVN to eclispe using Subversive client without errors?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

Whenever I am trying to import a code to Eclipse from SVN directly the project is not detected as an android project. 
This is what i do .. In eclispe > Import Android project >From SVN > Checkout as a project with the name specified >  ...

Now the imported code appears as a project in package explorer, but not as an android project. So there is no run as android project in the Right-click menu.

So I import the checked out code into eclispe once again and It shows a lot of errors in the Code  which was not there in the original code. 
Sometimes it shows "Unable to resolve markers" and shows some 3 or 4 marker ids while importing the code.
The same happens when I import any code checked out from the svn using any other client.
Please resolve the issue. 
This happens only on Ubuntu and not in mac.
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Eclipse: Juno
Java:JDk7u7

Comment: Stupid question, but after importing have you tried going to Project -> Clean -> select all and do a rebuilt. Unable to resolve markers sounds like a builder issue, doing a clean might help this. Not posting this as an answer because I don't know if it will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tird all that . But still its showing the same errors .. I hav etried clearing the svn files as well .. It wont work ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the version of Java compiler. The project was done in Java compiler version 1.6 and the imported code has its properties set to Java 1.5. I changed the Java version from 1.5 to 1.6 In project properties and it's solved.